# Is it correct to say that every bijection of a set onto itself is a permutation?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, symmetric-groups

Typically permutations are discussed in the context of finite sets.  I seem to recall, however, at least one source saying that every bijection of a set onto itself is a permutation.  That was in the context of discussing the transformations of the Euclidean plane.

Is it a generally accepted definition to say that a permutation is any bijection of a set onto itself?

Comment: Yes, what else would they be?

Comment: Yes, see [Permutation : Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA from the tag description: "Symmetric group is a group consisting of all permutations of given **finite** set with composition as the binary operation."  Which didn't stop me from selecting it.

Comment: "Permutation" sometimes also means "bijection that fixes all but finitely many points". It is an important distinction because such permutations on infinite set have a sign (unlike general bijections). And for example those with positive sign form an infinite simple group.

Comment: @freakish I don't want to get to far ahead of myself.  I asked the question because I wanted a term to use in my personal study notes, and I prefer to keep them as reliable as is reasonable.  But I am curios to know if this *parity*, if you will, is related to the even/odd distinction found in traditional permutations of finite ordered sets.  I'm thinking in terms of the Levi-Civita (symbol, tensor, pseudo-tenosr) tensor density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no" -- there is no universally accepted standard for the term "permutation" on an infinite set.  See discussions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1072/definition-of-infinite-permutations) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17653/infinite-permutations).  Two natural choices are the definition presented (all bijections), and the set of all bijections with all but finitely many points fixed.

Comment: Well I guess you only need find one instance of somebody using "permutation" to mean something other than "bijection" to justify your answer, but I am still inclined to disagree with you. There are many papers around on infinite permutation groups, and they all appear to use "permutation" to mean "bijection" and to talk about permutations of bounded support to mean those with support less than some specified cardinal.

Comment: I acknowledge the subjectivity to my question. Most discussions of permutation involved finite sets.  OTOH, I am confident that my source was first-rate.  Perhaps https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke and/or something by Hermann Weyl.  Often terminology is field-dependent.  For example, when discussing tensor indices, we typically think about the actual ordering of elements.  The wikipedia article encourages us to think of permutations as transformations.  To me, the deepest understanding will not distinguish between these views.

Comment: I decided to accept this answer since, the more I thought about it, the more I realized that there is reasonable grounds for disputing the applicability to infinite sets, and especially continuous sets.